# Alternative til jQuery Lazyload

Tags: jquery-plugins, lazy-loading

I have searched and searched, but didn't find what I was looking for, so sorry if it's already there. I did a photo blog for a friend and used to implement jQuery Jazyload (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) to load all the pictures along the way, however, it doesn't work in all browsers anymore and he stopped developing it. I heard of http://www.sebastianoarmelibattana.com/projects/jail/, but it will need a lot of extra text and code when you have 500-1,000 pictures on one site. Also I want to be able to load the images lets say 1000px, before they appear in the window.

Do anyone have suggestions/solution or else, to get the problem fixed?
You can view his site here: www.theblackguido.com (NSFW)

Thank you in advance.

Kristian

Answer (score 1):

It is the part of automatically removing image src which does not work anymore. Version 1.5 released Dec 23, 2009 provided alternative where you must alter HTML and store image url in `original` attribute. I renamed it recently to `data-original`to be HTML5 friendly. I also updated to [documentation](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) which better explains how to use it.

But yes. The way [Lazy Load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) used to work is not possible anymore. Before you could just drop in the JavaScript and it handled everything automagically. Due to changes in new browsers you now must alter the HTML.

PS. Lazy Load is not dead. It was just orphan for a while.

Comment: Question for you. I want to add lazy load to a photo blog with thousands of photos already in place. Obviously, modifying the HTML at this point would be a nightmare. Wondering if I use Javascript to replace the src attribute and add/populate the data-original attribute, and then call lazy load, will that work? I know new browsers load the src attribute even if it is removed. But the src is changed, will it still load the original?

Comment: Just tested out my above question/theory and it does not work. It still loads the images. Apparently, any image/file that is specified in a src attribute gets loaded, no matter what.

Comment: Removed or changed. It does not matter.

Comment: Why not load first the alter script before the lazyload gets called i thing it will work.